# No such file or directory in MAC Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, cocoapods

I want to access to a directory of an xcode project that contains cocoapods (firebase framework) in my Desktop! But I keep getting: No such file or directory!  [image: As here]

I tried to access to another non-project folder and it worked.
It also worked when I tried to access to a project folder that does not contain cocoapods!

I don't know why I could not access to any project folder that contains cocoapods!

When I list the contents of the desktop I got:[image: here]
There is an @ in the properties
What does that means and how can I access to the folder?
I just want to upload it to the Github? any solutions?

Comment: just try to list the present folders in the directory and see if the folder you are trying to access is listed. Try with "ls -al" command

Comment: Just see the properties of that folder in the command line and see if it is locked or some sort of restriction is there...

Comment: There are no restrictions at all as here: http://screenshot.net/8qoz4u0. Here is what inside the folder: http://screenshot.net/p36xjiy

Comment: I noticed that there's an @ What does that mean? Is related to no being able to access to the folder?

Comment: How can I fix that please?

Comment: Share the screen where you found "@".

Answer (score 0):

BusinessWallet is probably a framework bundle, which means that it is actually just one file, but appears as a directory in Finder. You can copy individual files out of it in Finder.

If you need programmatic access to contents inside the bundle, take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html

Comment: I just want to access to it to upload the contents to github! How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a Mac professional user! Can you explain with more details, please?

Comment: When you open BusinessWallet in Finder, you should be able to drag all the contents to another directory and then you can do what you want with the files. Make sure you press Alt while you drag them, or they will be removed from the bundle.